# How to upload CSV with a merged datetime to Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have been trying to load a csv file to BigQuery but I got the below error.

What can I write in the schema to help resolve this error? or a way to separate the date and time for BigQuery to read it?

Date format: [4/12/2016  7:21:00 AM]

"Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM' as TIMESTAMP for field Time (position 1) starting at location 15 with message 'Invalid time zone: AM'"

Thank you in advance!

No idea how to process. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using parse_timestamp() on the string? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, it's trying to pickup what timezone is used in the timestamp field, but is erroring out because a timezone is not set. You'd only be able to seperate the date and time after the table has imported so you could instead import the field as a string and then remake the table in BigQuery and reformatting the field using something like

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z',
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', created_date)
  ) AS created_date
```